# How to run your own file in Manim

Tags: python, terminal, manim

Even I have a question,
Some of you might be familiar with Manim(3blue1browns math animation software). If not here is the GitHub page(by thereom of Beethoven) it actually just says about the installation-https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/0_instalation/macOS/INSTRUCTIONS.md

My problem is that I want to run my code but not the example scenes. Please tell me if you have the answer. I use sublime text Thank you.

Comment: Let me clarify if I understand your question: You don't know how to run your own script? If so, you can follow my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI2YJff9SgI&list=PL2B6OzTsMUrwo4hA3BBfS7ZR34K361Z8F&index=6).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you specify it in your terminal:

```sh
python -m manim <name_script.py> <scene_name> -<flags>
```

But the file must be in the manim folder (which contains the manimlib folder).

Comment: OMG! It's TheoremOfBeethoven! It's such a pleasure to meet you. Thank you!